# React native navigation button in the header with parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

There is a button in the header that is suppose to go to detail page and send parameters. The issue I am having is that when the button is clicked nothing happens. Could you help with this.
I am not sure how to insert navigation button in the header and pass parameters to a screen

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          
          headerRight: (navigation) => (
            <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => {
          /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
          navigation.navigate('Details', {
            itemId: 86,
            otherParam: 'anything you want here',
          });
        }}
      />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the `navigation` param to the `options` prop of the screen.

Try something like this:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeScreen}
  options={({navigation}) => ({
    headerRight: () => (
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => {
          /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
          navigation.navigate('Details', {
            itemId: 86,
            otherParam: 'anything you want here',
          });
        }}
      />
    ),
  })
/>
```